# The command "".\Bin\mt.exe" -nologo -manifest ... exited with error code 3 in CCNET

Tags: .net-3.5, msbuild, ccnet-config

I am trying to build my VS 2008 project in CCNEt and getting the below error

```
 <message level="high"><![CDATA[".\Bin\mt.exe" -nologo -manifest "C:\MyProject\MyFile.exe.manifest" -outputresource:"C:\MyProject\bin\Release\MyFile.exe;#1"]]></message>

<message level="high"><![CDATA[The system cannot find the path specified.]]></message>

<error code="MSB3073" file="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets" line="3397" column="13"><![CDATA[The command "".\Bin\mt.exe" -nologo -manifest "C:\MyProject\MyFile.exe.manifest" -outputresource:"C:\MyProject\bin\Release\MyFile.exe;#1" exited with code 3.]]></error>
```

This project builds happily on my local server.

ALso there is no Bin folder in M.Net\Framework\v3.5....

Any help will be awesome

I also did an msbuild on the project and got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the above message

it's most likely coz you are trying to build your solution on a server which has Visual Studio 2008 or the .net Framework 3.5 SDK not installed

and are copying files from your dev computer to server to make things work

well here is the solution

copy the

C:\program files\Microsoft SDKs

folder (thanks @leppie for that)

to your CCNet / build server.

Next you need to update the registry
telling the .net framework where the SDK is

See below screenshot for details

you will have to create the Windows key and then add the strings
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/791375b079.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/791375b079.png)

Answer (score 1):

error 3 is "The system cannot find the path specified."

suggest trying sysinternals procmon to see what it is looking for (And failing to find)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path to the `SDK\bin` directory.

EG:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
```

Comment: but where?? Sorry I tried it under the "path environment variable" and 

changed the node value from       <FrameworkSDKDir>@(_TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryItem)</FrameworkSDKDir>

to

<FrameworkSDKDir>c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\</FrameworkSDKDir>

(c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\ is where my SDK is)

in
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets

but then it said it couldn't find the file

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\.Bin\mt.exe"

Comment: Well remove the bin from either path... (and that `.`).

Comment: but its not there - that's the problem