# Addressing "Access Denied" Exception with WMI Calls

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, wmi

I'm getting an exception with a message of "Access Denied" when executing against a WMI request.  Some WMI requests appear to require higher security privileges than others.  Ultimately my goal is to monitor process launches within the system and log.  Regardless if there is a better approach, its now become a vendetta in getting this WMI approach to work.

I've attempted the code at [Security Tools -> WMI Programming Using C#.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/securitytools/wmi-programming-using-c-net) and still receive the exception.  If you copy the code found in the blog entry you can reproduce my issue.

Another post on a similar topic can be found at [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510372/how-to-monitor-process-program-execution-in-windows) but again, try the code and you'll the see the same security exception.

How do I permit my code to execute these WMI requests?

I'm running on Windows 7 Pro and VS 2010 in a new C# command line project.

**Edit:**
Choosing "Run As Administrator" for the VS2010 instance and then executing the code works.  How do I automate this so a user doesn't have to manually elevate the privilege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these WMI calls may need admin privileges. did you try right clicking your .exe file  and selecting "Run As Administrator"?

[Add a manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to your program so that it always runs with Admin privileges. [Here](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx) is another link which is more to the point.

Comment: Yep, choosing "Run As Administrator" for the VS2010 instance and then executing the code works.  How do I automate this so a user doesn't have to manually elevate the privilege?  (Editing the question to reflect this).

Comment: Nims - thank you for the information.  I've followed the instructions and I can manually execute the manifest application (mt.exe) to create the .exe with embedded manifest.  However, using a post-build step doesn't work.  I've modified it even based on comments in the page - any ideas?  It always errors with "...exited with code 3."

Comment: error 3 is "The system cannot find the path specified." see if giving the absolute path to mt.exe solves the issue. There is a sttackoverflow question on this error here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505612/the-command-bin-mt-exe-nologo-manifest-exited-with-error-code-3-in-ccn

Answer (score 0):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverhyperv/thread/2a7e8ba9-2a9e-46c2-8233-3eb65cfd16cc

This will help u..