# Access denied when adding an Ethernet printer port with WMI on Windows XP 64 bit

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I've been writing a printer driver installer. Among other things it can create an Ethernet printer, which means I need to create an Ethernet printer port.

The code I've used to create the port (see below) works fine on Windows XP 32 bit, Windows Vista 32 & 64 bit and Windows 7 32 & 64 bit. However when the code is run on Windows XP 64 bit I get an access denied exception.

Here is the C# code, boiled down to a simple form which produces the error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ManagementClass portClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort");
    ManagementObject portObject = portClass.CreateInstance();

    portObject["Name"] = "TestPort";
    portObject["HostAddress"] = "172.16.2.78";
    portObject["PortNumber"] = 9100;
    portObject["Protocol"] = 1;
    portObject["SNMPEnabled"] = false;

    PutOptions options = new PutOptions();
    options.Type = PutType.UpdateOrCreate;
    try
    {
        portObject.Put(options);
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ManagementException: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

When running the program I am logged in as administrator, and I've also tried right clicking and doing a "Run as" administrator, but it doesn't have an effect. I also have a manifest to force the application to run as admin in Windows Vista/7; I am not sure how that affects Windows XP 64 bit.

Most of the information I've found online so far deals with using WMI on a remote machine, but all of this is for the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

> When running the program I am logged in as administrator and I've also
>   tried right clicking and doing a "Run as" administrator but it doesn't
>   have an effect.

This context menu item was not added until Windows Vista.  How exactly are you doing this on Windows XP?  Have you tried to adjust the manfest file?

I wish I could actually provide an answer, but your question is missing important details and/or makes a statement that makes no sense ( i.e. "run as administrator on Windows XP" ).

From the Following Question: [Addressing "Access Denied" Exception with WMI Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020217/addressing-access-denied-exception-with-wmi-calls/3020404#3020404)

> [Add a manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to your program so that it always runs with Admin
>   privileges. [Here](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx) is another link which is more to the point.

Comment: Windows XP 64 bit has a context menu item "Run as..." which brings [this window](http://imgur.com/yCMh7). Unchecking the "Run this program with restricted access" or running as the user "Administrator" have no effect. I also have a manifest to run as admin on Vista/7.

Comment: What you describe is not same feature as "run as administrator" by a long shot.  If you run the application as a user with administrator powers does the program complain about the permissions?

Comment: Yes, no matter how I run the application on XP 64 it gives the Access Denied error.

Comment: This is not an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I would have loved to make it a comment, had to much to say, I had no other choice.  Its also the reason I reported the question, I don't believe in its current state, it can even be answered.